# Getting Error While Inserting JSON object into JSOUP

Tags: java, json, jsoup, saiku

I was trying to post some json objects into Saiku Server using JSOUP. Here is my code.

```
Response document1 = Jsoup
         .connect(
           "http://localhost:8080/saiku/rest/saiku/admin/datasources/")
           .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
           .data(testJson.toJSONString())
     .ignoreContentType(true)
         .referrer("http://localhost:8080/")
         .cookie("JSESSIONID", res.cookie("JSESSIONID"))
          .userAgent(
           "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36")
         .method(Method.POST).timeout(10000).execute();
```

and I am getting error like

```
 Errorjava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply an even number of key value pairs .
```

I searched in many sites but can't able to find the solution for that . Can someone clarify me . Thanks in Advance. i attached my code here,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the requestBody() for posting the JSON object.The requestBody() method is only available in the JSOUP 1.9.1 jar and i posted the code below for your reference.

```
    // JSON Object
    JSONObject testJson = new JSONObject();

    testJson.put("connectionname", "drinkss");
    testJson.put("jdbcurl", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/drink");
    testJson.put("schema", "datasources/dr.xml");
    testJson.put("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    testJson.put("username", "root");
    testJson.put("password", "211218");
    testJson.put("connectiontype", "MONDRIAN");

    // For Posting datasource into server
    Response document1 = Jsoup
            .connect(
                    "http://localhost:8080/saiku/rest/saiku/admin/datasources/")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .requestBody(testJson.toString())
            .data(testJson)
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .referrer("http://localhost:8080/")
            .cookie("JSESSIONID", res.cookie("JSESSIONID"))
            .userAgent(
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36")
            .method(Method.POST).timeout(10000).execute();
    System.out.println("post successfully....."
            + testJson.toJSONString());
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy, It Works .

Answer (score 1):

According to the [javadoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/):

```
Connection data(String... keyvals)
```

> Add a number of request data parameters. Multiple parameters may be set at once, e.g.: .data("name", "jsoup", "language", "Java", "language", "English"); creates a query string like: ?name=jsoup&language=Java&language=English

I think you need:

```
Connection requestBody(String body)
```

> Set a POST (or PUT) request body. Useful when a server expects a plain request body, not a set for URL encoded form key/value pairs